# llvm-mca for ARM Cortex-M cores

Tags: optimization, arm, cpu-architecture, cortex-m, llvm-mca

I'd like to use the [`llvm-mca`](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-mca.html) tool to view execution timelines for instruction sequences in ARM Cortex-M cores, e.g. the Cortex-M4. I can see that there is [support for in-order cores](https://reviews.llvm.org/D94928), but I'm not sure if these cores are supported by `llvm-mca`. Concretely, I'm looking for the specific command-line options that I need to pass in order to analyze code for this architecture. [Here's what I tried in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rh74hKdn5), but I'm getting an error and I'm out of ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: since on all processors execution time is primarily determined by the fetch/memory system and not the core itself, how is this modeled in this tool?  At least with cortex-m's it is chip specific and not as dynamic as typical cortex-a applications,  but still how would it be possible to make a generic tool (that is of any value)?

Comment: what results are you expecting from such a tool, if it existed? (if it were possible)